# rxjs updated gives error with mapping

Tags: angular

I recently updated my version of rxjs from beta.2 to beta.11 and same to other packages now my `map` does not work... I tried to do same as here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1888 like others did, same error:

`Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.`

My `service.ts` looks like this:

```
import Rx from "rxjs"
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
constructor(private http: Http) { }

get(onNext: (json: any) => void) {
    this.http.get("api/random").map(response => response.json()).subscribe(onNext);
}}
```

and my package JSON looks like this (part of it):

```
  "dependencies": {
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
"jquery": "3.1.0",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
"systemjs": "0.19.36",
"zone.js": "0.6.15",
"typescript": "1.8.10"  },
```

Also i realised when I updated my `rxjs` from beta.2 to beta.11 the bundles folder changed there were also `Rx.js` and also `Rx.umd.js`, now only `Rx.umd.js` is left... Thought might be that visual studio does not download full library... However tried with `Node.js` also, same downloaded files... But cannot find anything on `rxjs` changelog about these changes... And if i downgrade it works fine...

Would be very appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I solved it importing the `Observable` from the main package instead of `rxjs/Observable`:

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';`

If that doesn't work, maybe try posting a Plunker. It's easier to replicate the issue and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution was in this topic : 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8518#issuecomment-229506507

and did this:

For VS 2015 (Update 3):

- Install VS 2015 Update 3
- Replace C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\typescriptServices.js with the file in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/Fix8518-U3/lib/typescriptServices.js. First take a local backup though.